# PHPExcel: Setting font size?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have been looking to change the font size of some Excel cells using a PHP library called PHPExcel.

This is what I tried:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setFontSize(16);
```

The method above does not work. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use `setSize` method instead `setFontSize`, it should work:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setSize(16);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use the *style array*, then you can do something like this:

```
$fontStyle = [
    'font' => [
        'size' => 16
    ]
];

$workbook->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle("F1:G1")
    ->applyFromArray($fontStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using **setSize** or **applyFromArray** to setting font size, like code below:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setSize(16);
```

OR

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->applyFromArray(array(
    "font"  => array(
        "size"  => 16
    )
));
```